# python remove duplicates from 2 lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from 2 lists. so I wrote this function:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]

b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]

for i in b:
    if i in a:
        print "found " + i
        b.remove(i)

print b
```

But I find that the matching items following a matched item does not get remove.

I get result like this:

```
found ijk
found opq
['lmn', 'rst', '123', '456']
```

but i expect result like this:

['123', '456']

How can I fix my function to do what I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

Your problem seems to be that you're changing the list you're iterating over. Iterate over a copy of the list instead.

```
for i in b[:]:
    if i in a:
        b.remove(i)


>>> b
['123', '456']
```

But, How about using a list comprehension instead?

```
>>> a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
>>> b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]
>>> [elem for elem in b if elem not in a ]
['123', '456']
```

Comment: If the `a` list grows longer it may turn out that turning it into a `set` is a lot more efficient (`x in s` is O(1) for sets, O(n) for lists) according to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 38):

Here is what's going on. Suppose you have this list:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and you are looping over every element in the list.  Suppose you are currently at index position 1:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
       ^
       |
   index = 1
```

...and you remove the element at index position 1, giving you this:

```
['a',      'c', 'd']
       ^
       |
    index 1
```

After removing the item, the other items slide to the left, giving you this:

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
       ^
       |
    index 1
```

Then when the loop runs again, the loop increments the index to 2, giving you this:

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
            ^ 
            |
         index = 2
```

See how you skipped over 'c'?  The lesson is: never delete an element from a list that you are looping over.

Answer (score 28):

What about

```
b= set(b) - set(a)
```

If you need possible repetitions in `b` to also appear repeated in the result and/or order to be preserved, then

```
b= [ x for x in b if not x in a ]
```

would do.

Comment: This answer was downvoted once. Can anybody tell why? Any grave syntax/conceptual error? Not contributing to the question asked (and considering that sometimes it is extremely difficult to understand what is being asked)?  Bad English to the point of unintelligibility?

Comment: I saw `if not x in a`, it's a bit strange for me. It also works well, but I think you should change it to `if x not in a` will make the code clearer. My personal opinion.

Comment: Note that the list comprehension option here must be written: `[x for x in d if not (x in o )]` to pass pep8.

Answer (score 6):

You asked to **remove both the lists duplicates**, here's my solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]

x = OrderedDict.fromkeys(a)
y = OrderedDict.fromkeys(b)

for k in x:
    if k in y:
        x.pop(k)
        y.pop(k)


print x.keys()
print y.keys()
```

Result:

```
['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
['123', '456']
```

The nice thing here is that you keep the order of both lists items

Answer (score 3):

or a set

```
set(b).difference(a)
```

be forewarned sets will not preserve order if that is important

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda functions.

```
f = lambda list1, list2: list(filter(lambda element: element not in list2, list1))
```

The duplicated elements in list2 are removed from list1.

```
>>> a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
>>> b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456"]
>>> f(a, b)
['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
>>> f(b, a)
['123', '456']
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of avoiding the problem of editing a list while you iterate over it, is to use comprehensions:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]
b = [x for x in b if not x in a]
```

Comment: Same solution posted 1h ago by Mario Rossi and Sukrit Kalra.

Comment: Perhaps @Mayur Patel started writing it at the same time than me. This is a topic for meta (I guess): either blocking questions when 1 (or perhaps 2) people are answering them (for certain amount of time?), or at least an indication of how many other people is answering them.  I mean before the answers are **posted**.  I'm a noobie, though.  If something like this is already there, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list comprehensive

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]
```

duplicates value removed from a

```
c=[value for value in a if value not in b]
```

duplicate value removed from b

```
c=[value for value in b if value not in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already many answers on "how can you fix it?", so this is a "how can you improve it and be more pythonic?": since what you want to achieve is to get the difference between list `b` and list `a`, you should use difference operation on sets ([operations on sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)):

```
>>> a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
>>> b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]
>>> s1 = set(a)
>>> s2 = set(b)
>>> s2 - s1
set(['123', '456'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of 7stud, if you go through the list in reversed order, you don't have the problem you encountered:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]

b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456", ]

for i in reversed(b):
    if i in a:
        print "found " + i
        b.remove(i)

print b

Output:
found rst
found opq
found lmn
found ijk
['123', '456']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]

b = ["ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "123", "456","abc"]

for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print("found", i)
        b.remove(i)
print(b)

output:
found abc
found ijk
found lmn
found opq
found rst
['123', '456']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).