# How to filter a list

Tags: python

Im writing a simple function to take out any odd numbers from a list and return a list of only the even ones.

```py
def purify(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        if i%2!=0:
            numbers.remove(i)
    return numbers    

print(purify([4,5,5,4]))
```

However, the above returns:

```py
[4, 5, 4]
```

Why doesn't the second 5 get removed as it also meets the if condition?

Im looking less for a different method to the problem and more to understand why this happens.

Comment: if the list is long, you can get rid of duplicates with numbers = list(set(numbers)) before scanning. In this example its not worth it but for big data sets it would be good to eliminate redundant checks up front

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you remove an item, the items that follow get moved one position to the left. This results in the loop skipping some items.

BTW, a more idiomatic way to write that code is

```
numbers = [num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: This post explains the method of list construction that @NPE is describing. It's called list comprehension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061760/how-to-read-aloud-python-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 14):

One option I didn't see mentioned was, ironically `filter`:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not x % 2, [4,5,5,4])
[4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing from `numbers`, try creating a new list appending only the values that meet your conditions.

```
def purify(numbers):
    newNumber = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i%2 ==0:
           newNumber.append(i)
    return newNumber    

>>>print purify([4,5,5,4])
[4, 4]
```

Or even simpler:

```
def purify(numbers):
    return [i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]

print purify([4,5,5,4])
```

Comment: The second way of doing it is a way better, specially when handling big lists.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. just add [:] after for i in numbers which will iterate through a copy of the list.

```
def purify(numbers):
    for i in numbers[:]:
        if i%2!=0:
            numbers.remove(i)
    return numbers    

print purify([4,5,5,4])
```

Theres a good explanation below

[python remove duplicates from 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194968/python-remove-duplicates-from-2-lists)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> listToPurify = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5]
>>> purified = [i for i in listToPurify if i % 2]
>>> purified
[1, 3, 5, 5]
```

Seems that NPE posted this before me! If you're confused about list comprehensions, check out [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

If you'd prefer to use a `for` loop, you're going to have to deal with the fact that the length of the list is changing.

Answer (score 0):

For more clear picture print the list in each iteration and see what is happening to list and see how the iteration continues.

```
# i have taken all odd number to try to remove all numbers from list
>>> list = [1,3,5,7]
>>> for num in list:
...     if num % 2 != 0:
...         list.remove(num)
...     print(list)
...
[3, 5, 7]
[3, 7]
```

You could see that elements moved one position to the left on each remove().