# I wrote a code that would print the odd numbers or the even numbers in a list according to users choice. But the append not working inside the def

Tags: python, list, function, append

I created a code that takes a list from the user and then asks the user to choose from printing only the odd numbers or the even numbers. But whenever the user choice is taken, the execution freezes. Using keyboard interrupt, I find that the execution stopped in either the odd or even function. Please help !!!

here is the code:

```
    from os import lstat

    def odd(lst,oddlst):
        for i in range(0,n):
            while(lst[i]%2!=0):
                oddlst.append(lst[i])
        return oddlst

    def even(lst,evenlst):
        for i in range (0,n):
            while(lst[i]%2==0):
                evenlst.append(lst[i])
        return evenlst

    lst = []
    oddlst = []
    evenlst = []
    n = int(input("enter number of elements \n"))
    print("\nenter the elements \n")
    for i in range(0,n):
        num = int(input())
        lst.append(num)
    print(lst)

    choice = input(" Do you want to print odd elements or even elements \n (odd/even) 
    \n")
    if(choice=="odd"):
        odd(lst,oddlst)
        print(oddlst)
    elif(choice=="even"):
        even(lst,evenlst)
        print(evenlst)
    else:
        print("invalid choice")
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `if` instead of `while`?

Comment: because your code goes into an infinite loop when you are using a while loop inside for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use an `if` instead of a `while` in your `odd` and `even` functions.

The reason your execution "freezes", is that you run into an infinite loop.
In either while, the `i`-th element gets checked, then appended to a list. But the condition, against which you are checking, doesn't change, neither does the index `i`.

Changing your `while`s to `if`s should solve your problem.

Also, for a more elegant solution to your problem, have a look at:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter 
[How to filter a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217033/how-to-filter-a-list)