# Delete array elements while looping in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to delete all elements from an array.  For example:

```
@array = [1,2,3,4,5]
@array.each do |element|
  @array.delete(element)
end
```

Now, I understand why the code above does not work.  However, I am tasked with deleting all elements of an array while using this `delete_entry` method:

```
def delete_entry(entry)
   @array.delete(entry)
end
```

I have read that removing elements in the midst of iteration is disallowed by design in ruby.  Any ideas as to how I would go about deleting all elements from an array while using the `delete_entry` method in my implementation?

Comment: [`Array#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)?

Comment: That was my initial thought: `@array.delete_if { true }`.  But I am required to use the `delete_entry` method.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say, "removing elements of a receiver while enumerating over them is dicouraged..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :array

  def initialize
    @array = [1, 2, 3]
  end

  def delete_entry(entry)
     @array.delete(entry)
  end
end


d = Dog.new

d.array.length.times do 
  d.delete_entry(d.array[0])
end

p d.array

--output:--
[]
```

> I have read that removing elements in the midst of iteration is
>   disallowed by design in ruby.

Ridiculous.  It just won't work as you may expect.  Here's why:

[deleting elements from an array while iterating over the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194968/python-remove-duplicates-from-2-lists/18195153#18195153)

Comment: What is the point of class creation? your approach as simple as these 2 lines: `@array = [1,2,3,4,5];
@array.size.times { |element| @array.delete(@array[0]) }`

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, What is the point of using an `@variable` at the top level in your code?

Comment: in order not to create mysterious `Dog`s and just show the approach which op can apply to his code? If you don't like instance variables on top level what is stopping you from writing `array = [1,2,3,4,5]; array.size.times { |element| array.delete(array[0]) }` I just don't understand how `Dog` is related with question and artificial code complication

Comment: Do you ask what is the point of writing 2 lines of code instead of 20? :)

Comment: @Rustam A. Gasanov, ***If you don't like instance variables on top level what is stopping you from writing array = [1,2,3,4,5];***  Because that wasn't the op's code.  Your example does the same thing to the main object and the Object class(ignoring private access) that my code does to a dog instance and the Dog class--except that you have exposed a global method to all objects instead of limiting its scope to the Dog class.  OKAY?!  The op's example seemed to come from inside a class, so I mimicked that class with the Dog class.

Answer (score 3):

```
def delete_entry(entry)
  @array.delete(entry)
end

@array = [1,2,3,4,5]

delete_entry(@array.first) until @array.empty?
@array #=> []
```

I think this reads better than using an enumerator and requires fewer operations when `@array` contains duplicate values.

Comment: `[nil, nil, false, false]`?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array in reverse:

```
@array = [1,2,3,4,5]
@array.reverse_each do |element|
  @array.delete(element)
end
p @array # => []
```

Comment: *Builds a temporary array and traverses that array in reverse order.*

Comment: @7stud, [Array#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each) is an enumerator, so no temporary array is constructed. When given a block, it returns the receiver, just as `Array.each` does.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, Yeah, I quoted the Enumerable docs--I didn't realize Array had a reverse_each().

Answer (score 1):

```
@array = [1,2,3,4,5]
@_array = @array.clone
@_array.each do |element|
  delete_entry(element)
end
```