# how to remove several elements of a list by value?

Tags: python, list, redo

I have two lists of A and B. When I found a value of B in A, I want to remove the value in A. But without "redo" in python, it makes a problem. There might be diverse codings for that but I want to know a very smart or simple or pythonic coding.

I need "redo" for this, but python does not have "redo".

```
A = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
B = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
for mon in A:
    if mon in B:
        A.remove(mon)
print(A)
```

returns  ['Jan', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jun']

After removing 'Feb' in A, due to the A.remove() method, 'Mar' is skipped.

I need to explain my case more because there are many kinds of solutions. Basically I want to keep A because A is a reference with long list elements. Then during a looping of many B's, I want to remove those elements in B from A. So I need to keep A until the end of program, removing elements which belongs to any B.

Comment: that solved my problem. but the title is somewhat differrent so I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[item for item in A if item not in B]
```

Comment: I would agree with this answer but to just add it is bad to add or remove from a list that you are iterating over, it never ends well and I would think that this is the reason why you are having issues.

Comment: This is an answer. But following the extended (edited) my question, it might be a troublesome to make a new list rather than keeping A. In my opinion, Sukrit' solution [in duplicate page((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194968/python-remove-duplicates-from-2-lists))] looks best , which changes just A into a copy of A[:]. I am not sure there is any weak point there.

Comment: If you don't want to set up a new list, you might want to use `A = [item for item in A if item not in B]`

Answer (score 2):

iterate over items in list B:

```
A = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
B = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']

for item in B:
    if item in A:
        A.remove(item)

print (A)
```

output:

```
['Jan', 'May', 'Jun']
```

> NOTE:
>
> whats happening in your code, you are iterating over items in a list
>   from which you are removing items. **the for loop continues its
>   iteration from the index on which it stays.** but if you remove item
>   from the list,you have moved your items for idx -1, because of that its
>   "skiping" some items from your list A

Example:

1.iter: 'Jan' (index 0) its not in the list B

2.iter: 'Feb' (index 1) its in the list B, remove 'Feb' from list A, after removing item, at index 1 now you will have 'Mar', but index where iteration is continuing is 2, because of that its "skipping" 'Mar'

Answer (score 1):

Use `set.difference`

**Ex:**

```
A = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
B = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']

print(list(set(A).difference(set(B))))
```

**Output:**

```
['Jan', 'May', 'Jun']
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalization of this question across multiple lists to get a list of common elements:

```
l = [['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'], ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'], ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Dec']]

list(set.intersection(*map(set, l)))
```

Output:

```
['Feb', 'Apr', 'Mar']
```